# Return same values in two lists Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

If i have

```
findmatching([2,4,1,7], [4,9,1,8], X).

X = [4,1]
```

I'm trying to use member, and find all, but on back tracking if member does not find a value it terminates my program

Thanks

Comment: `?- intersection([2,4,1,7], [4,9,1,8], X).` yields `X = [4, 1].`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are trying to find the intersection of two sets (which there is probably a great answer for already on here somewhere, because it is a common problem to have to solve).

I would solve it like this:

```
% an empty list intersects with nothing
findmatching([], _, []).

% Matches is the intersection of the set defined by List1 and the set
%  defined by List2
findmatching([List1H|List1T], List2, Matches) :-
    memberchk(List1H, List2) ->
        (findmatching(List1T, List2, MatchesT),
        Matches = [List1H|MatchesT])
        ;
        findmatching(List1T, List2, Matches).
```

In this predicate if the head of List1 appears in List2 then Matches should be any matches from the tail of List1 plus the head of List1. If the head of List1 doesn't appear in List2 then Matches should be just the matches from the tail of List1 (and the head of List1 is forgotten about).

Comment: should work, but you can make it more compact *and* more efficient using idiomatic Prolog: place patterns in arguments and use -> instead of repeating member. Also, memberchk is meant to be used instead of member, and append/3 can be avoided consing in the 2^ argument of the recursive call

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make the changes you suggested and edit my answer a little later on!

Comment: Your suggestions made for a much clearer (and more concise) result. Thanks!

Comment: you're on track to make your Prolog better (+1). But note that placing patterns in arguments yields not only more more compact code, but also more understandable and efficient. I.e. `findmatching([List1H|List1T], List2, Matches) :-`

Comment: Thank you very much, your tips are appreciated!